# Adding Category option : cannot read get

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I'm trying to add a category option and by doing so appearently broke some things.

**This is my code :**

namespace/module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_id', [
            'type'     => 'int',
            'label'    => 'Enable Mega Menu',
            'input'    => 'boolean',
            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '0',
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'General Information',
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="enable_megamenu">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Mega Menu</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Error that i now have :**

Disabling or enabling the module does not change anything.
My category admin page is not completing its loading anymore (it keeps a loading icon in the middle). 
I have the next output error in my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Documentation that i used :
[Documentation magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html)

**Image on request :**

[image: Troubleshoot]

Comment: Any error please add in question. I will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked in my local. it is working fine. The problem is on category name

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_id',
```

Change to

```
  $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'enable_megamenu',
```

For more reference for further :

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-new-category-attributes/

Comment: This indeed is something i overlooked. But i think i broke something. Maybe i need to do a rollback :D I will mark this as an answer because this is prob because i did something wrong debugging this.

Comment: if any error please post i will help you :)

Comment: At this point i have removed the module entirely. Still getting the same error. I will need to do some more debugging but if i have any issues after that i will surely ask you. Thank you for you help!

Comment: I has been a while but now i have time for this once again. I have uninstalled the module and reinstalled it with this adjustment but i still get the same error : Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. Also it just does not create anything within the database with 'enable_megamenu'

Comment: i will check and update. it is through is js error or magento error

Comment: Well i noticed that i didn't declare a namespace (derp) so now the datbase option is enabled. I'm going to read and execture the rest of that article and see where i end up. I will let you know , thanks!

Comment: I have made a chat where we maybe can talk? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62473/room-for-swat-be-and-la-raison

Comment: It is a JS error. The full error is : multiselect.js:46  : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined and it comes from :                     this.normalizeData(this.source.get(this.dataScope)),

Comment: can you provide screen shot. it is comes only category page in backend only?

Comment: yes , screenshot in the orginal post

Comment: i will check and tell you

Comment: You can ignore this. The code change you put above works fine , i reinstalled the whole database and filles and it works now. Seems i messed up somewhere in the database.

Comment: To continue i made a new topic (so if you want to answer there i can atleast upvote and acces another answer of you ) ; https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184675/check-for-the-custom-category-setting

Comment: Sure  @SwAt.Be i will do