# Change navigation menu on setting

Tags: magento2, category, custom-options, navigation

I have set up a custom category setting called 'enable_megamenu'.

The code of that you can find [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/adding-category-option-cannot-read-get/182780#182780)

My question now is i also have a Plugin in my module and i was wondering how i can now check the value there. Do i need to make a Helper or how does this work? I have done it for normal custom setting before but never for these category settings.

Can someone help me out with that?

I thank you so much in advance!

edit : clarification. So idealy i want to do a

```
if ($enablemenu == 1) {
```

Edit 2 : Current Plugin MegaMenu.php is giving a blank page :

```
<?php

namespace Designit\Megamenu\Plugin;

class MegaMenu
{

    public function aroundGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
        $enablemenu  = $category->getData('enable_megamenu');

        if (!empty($enablemenu )) {
            //your code
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
    }

}
```

Edit 3 : I'm trying to get the top menu and overwrite it when enable_megamenu is enabled. Code so far :

```
<?php

namespace Designit\Megamenu\Plugin;
use \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;

class MegaMenu
{
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                                \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree) {
        $this->_menuTree = $menuTree;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

// Get cms page or current category page??
//return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
//        return $this->_registry->registry('current_cms_page');


    public function afterGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html)
    {

        $children = $this->_menuTree->getChildren();

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $enablemenu = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getData('enable_megamenu');

            if (!empty($enablemenu)) {
                // if mega menu is enabled in the backend
            } else {
                // Else
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This gives me the next error : Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $data of Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node.

Edit 4 :

I'm able to edit the menu now. I just need to know how to call for the option (if it is enabled or not)

code :

**Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, NodeFactory $nodeFactory, TreeFactory $treeFactory, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    )
    {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                    $child->getName()
                ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

}

?>
```

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

Comment: I am out of ideas to be honnest. This is a part of magento that i still need to learn. Anyone a clue how i can override the menu with my own custom mega menu when that option is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$enablemenu  = $category->getData('enable_megamenu');

if (!empty($enablemenu )) {
    //your code
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

Hope it will work.

**Comment by SwAt**

To get the ID (in Topmenu.php) i used

```
        $id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $child->getId());
```

Then its import not to use !empty because if you enable it and disable it again it gets a value but its 0 so change the code to validate :

```
        if ($getContent == 1) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do i need this in a Data helper? Or just in my Plugin? I come from Wordpress development mostly and i'm trying to figure this out :D Sorry

Comment: I added a new edit with the current code

Comment: Did you get value from $enablemenu ?

Comment: at the moment i just get a blank page when i use that code in my plugin MegaMenu.php

Comment: I editted the original post with what i'm trying now

Comment: So i'm at the point to test out your code but its not working. Where do you suggest putting it and how?

Comment: So what i ended up doing was using this code and get the id by using a bit of different  code (in Topmenu.php). I have updated in your post

Comment: Great @SwAt.Be!. I really appreciate your hard work. Thanks for editing and accepting my answer.